# How do I use JAXB to convert POJO into JSON

Tags: java, json, jaxb, annotations, jackson

I'm trying to use JAXB annotations to convert POJO into JSON and back in the way Jackson's default ObjectMapper doesn't work, i.e. rename fields and flag them to be not serialized. Though I couldn't find any documentation on how to use it without creating a servlet.

How do I convert string with JSON into (annotated) POJO and back?

Comment: where any of these answers helpfull ?

Comment: @Arno_Geismar Both answered a different question. I'll post my own answer as soon as I get time to extract the code from sources.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for @JsonIgnore ?
This annotation will mark a specific field so Jackson will ignore it when converting the POJO to JSON.

```
public class Foo(){
@JsonIgnore
String dontSerializeThis;
@JsonProperty
String serializeThis;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to stick with just JAXB annotations, Jackson supports `@XmlTransient`.  Jackson equates it to its native `@JsonIgnore` annotation.

From: http://wiki.fasterxml.com/JacksonJAXBAnnotations

> @javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlTransient
>
> ```
> Used to mark a class, field, or property as _transient_ (i.e. will not be serialized); that is, same as what @JsonIgnore would indicate
> ```

---

To enable processing of JAXB annotations in Jackson see the section *Registering JAXB annotation introspector* in the above link.

Comment: Incomplete answer. These are only the annotation, not how I actually get the json which is a String from the class instance.